# MySQL Scoring system - Getting a single users rank from a score cloud

Tags: mysql

I have a table of scores for games and users, users can have many scores for each game:

```
USER    GAME    SCORE   TIMESTAMP
1       1       125     123456
2       1       120     123457
1       2       10293   123458
2       2       10253   123459
1       1       130     123460
```

Obviously there are a lot more users and games, but you get the idea, I'm logging every score they get and storing it with a timestamp to get scores in specific timeframes.

What I need to do is to get a users individual rank in a game, for instance:

```
user 1 - game 1 - rank 1
user 2 - game 1 - rank 2
```

but doing a query

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user) 
FROM scores 
WHERE game = 1 
AND score > $user_2_score 
AND timestamp < $time_limit 
ORDER BY score DESC
```

will put the user in 3rd place because user 1 has two scores higher than it. I thought `COUNT(DISTINCT user)` would solve the problem but for some reason it didn't!

(obviously I am getting the users highest score from another query and passing it to this query)

Is there any way of doing this in MySQL, or a better query I could use to get better results?

Comment: Do you want that user have to apper with only highest scores?

Comment: yeah, and to count the number of users above them in the database, basically, i need to get their rank in the database

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using GROUP BY would be better :

```
SELECT user,game, SUM(score) AS scorer
FROM scores 
GROUP BY user, game
ORDER BY scorer DESC
```

Comment: He don't want to get the total sum (of scores) of games

Comment: Sorry, mine fault (didn't noticed) :)

Comment: I need to get their rank in the database, would that be done by changing SUM(score) to COUNT(user)?

Comment: No, getting the RANK is not simple as it seems you can't simply use a COUNT in most situations, you need a RANK Window function, but Mysql doesn't have window function at the moment ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get results for exact game, then you can use this query -

```
SELECT
  user,
  SUM(score) sum_score,
  @r:=@r + 1 rank
FROM
  scores, (SELECT @r:=0) t
WHERE
  game = 1
GROUP BY
  user
ORDER BY
  sum_score DESC;
```